# Nativescript CSS - Error: require's first parameter should be string

Tags: css, angular, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I got the following error when trying to create platform specific CSS for my app component. My android.css is working but common.css is not. Any ideas why?

```
JS: Error: /app.component.common.css does not start with /data/data/org.nativescript.portalestapp/files/app

JS: Error: Could not load CSS from /app.component.common.css: Error: require's first parameter should be string
```

I have the following files:
app.component.html

app.component.ts

app.component.common.css

app.component.android.css

app.component.ios.css

app.component.ts :

```
@Component({
    selector: "ns-app",
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: "app.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
```

app.component.common.css :

```
.page{
    background-color: #F4F5F7;
    font-family:Poppins-Regular, Poppins
}

.custom-action-bar {
    background-color:transparent;
}
```

app.component.android.css :

```
@import "/app.component.common.css";

.page {
    background-color: #fffffffa;
}
```

Comment: Did you try commenting the CSS rules one by one and see which line exactly causing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

```css
page{
    background-color: #F4F5F7;
    font-family:Poppins-Regular, Poppins
}

custom-action-bar {
    background-color:transparent;
}
```

Your first entry has to be a string